# Odd discoloration on wall outlet

Tags: outlet, color

[image: Odd Discoloration on Wall Outlet]

Just noticed a very odd brown looking discoloration (see image) on the top plug of a wall outlet. The items outlet has been in use without issue for awhile. Should I be concerned about the discoloration?

Looking at old photos, the dark brown spots seem to have been there for more than a year and since I started renting the place.

Comment: Likely heat and/or arcing. But given the shapes of the discoloration, I'd say arcing.

Comment: I'd be concerned about whatever was plugged in when that happened.

Comment: Lightning strike? Hard to imagine what else would cause an arc between neutral and protective Earth. Also, lightning might could do that even if nothing was plugged in to the outlet.

Comment: that looks like smoke stains, which suggest that the outlet has in the past overheated.  the wring that connects to to the outlet should be checked and the outlet inspected and if damaged replaced.

Comment: @SolomonSlow any arc would travel in behind the faceplate because the path is shorter ... that is a smoke stain

Comment: It was suggested that this belongs on DIY. With no answers I'd tend to agree BUT Godjihyo's answer is plausible and (proably :-) ) adds useful EE knowledge.

Comment: Think liquids and shorting

Answer (score 4):

I’ve seen this sort of thing quite a few times in electrical equipment that was in an environment with a lot if cigarette smoke. The fine nicotine particles are attracted to an electric field and leave an oily yellowish brown stain. If you wipe  it off with a white tissue and it looks yellowish there’s a good chance that’s what it is.

It wouldn’t hurt to check the wiring and replace the outlet though.